# Count "" (Empty Strings) on Same Row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this.

```
id ___ d1 ___ d2 ___ d3 ___ d4 ___ d5 ___ d6 ___ d7 ___ d8
----------------------------------------------------------
01 ___ XX ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" (There are 7 ""s)
02 ___ XX ___ XX ___ XX ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" (There are 5 ""s)
03 ___ XX ___ XX ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" (There are 6 ""s)
04 ___ XX ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" ___ "" (There are 7 ""s)
```

I want to see an output like this:

```
id ___ count
------------
01 ___ 7
02 ___ 5
03 ___ 6
04 ___ 7
```

How can I do that? Simply, I want to count empty strings but on same row.

Comment: These are empty strings, not NULLs, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `case` statement, and add up the results:

```
SELECT
    id
,   (    CASE d1 WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +    CASE d2 WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +    CASE d3 WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +    CASE d4 WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +    CASE d5 WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +    CASE d6 WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +    CASE d7 WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    +    CASE d7 WHEN '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) as TotalSpaces
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use the MySQL shortcut that treats a boolean as an integer:

```
select id,
       ((d1 = '') + (d2 = '') + (d3 = '') + (d4 = '') + (d5 = '') +
        (d6 = '') + (d7 = '') + (d8 = '')
       ) as "Count"
from table t;
```